# It won't even Send ctrl-alt-delete

Tags: windows-7-x64, autoit

What is the problem with this code, I know it should send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, but it doesn't!:

```
Sleep(1000)
Send("^!{DELETE}")
```

And this should send <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, which should lock the computer:

```
Sleep(1000)
Send("#l")
```

Why don't they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `Send` documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm):

> N.B. Windows does not allow the simulation of the "CTRL-ALT-DEL" combination!

Also, it seems others are unable to lock the computer using `Send("#l")`. You can use this, instead (from [this thread](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/139747-lock-computer/)):

```
dllcall("user32.dll","Int","LockWorkStation")
```